# not able to load image from asset folder, using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I have tried with Picasso to load image from asset folder

below is java code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_frame);

        getFilesList();

        ivMain = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivMain);

        Picasso.with(MainFrameActivity.this)
                .load("file:///android_asset/" + files.get(0)).into(ivMain);
    }

    private void getFilesList() {
        try {
            files = new ArrayList<String>();

            String f[] = getAssets().list("");
            for (String f1 : f) {

                if (f1.endsWith(".png")) {
                    System.out.println(f1);
                    files.add(f1);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

in System.out.println I am getting list of .png files

```
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): a1_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): a_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): b1_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): b_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): c1_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): c_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): d1_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): d_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): e1_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): e_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): f1_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): f_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): g1_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): g_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): h1_big.png
02-10 23:04:16.229: I/System.out(5863): h_big.png
```

but it is not loading in ivMain, is anybody has solution?

Comment: what string getting at `files.get(0)` ?

Comment: a.png ---- it's file name returning

Comment: To access files in the `assets` folder use `AssetManager.list()` and `AssetManager.open(...)` as written in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list(java.lang.String)